# How to know if my Canon T2i can support infrared photography?

Tags: canon, canon-550d, infrared

I have a Canon T2i, and I'm wondering if I can take some IR photos with it.

Answer (score 12):

To an extent yes your camera can support IR photography. It has an IR filter but if you mount a visible light blocking filter on the lens and use a long enough exposure you can record images in infra red.

Alternatively you can have the IR filter on the sensor replaced with a visible light blocking filter and shoot images handheld without anything on the lens.

See also:

- [Is it possible to do infrared photography with digital cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/912/is-it-possible-to-do-infrared-photography-with-digital-cameras)
- [What companies offer an IR camera filter?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8747/what-companies-offer-an-ir-camera-filter)
- [What are the benefits of infrared conversion?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11211/what-are-the-benefits-of-infrared-conversion)
- [Are infrared DSLR conversion companies safe? What about DIY infrared conversion?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9339/are-infrared-dslr-conversion-companies-safe-what-about-diy-infrared-conversion)
- [What is the best choice of filter for infrared photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13446/what-is-the-best-choice-of-filter-for-infrared-photography)

Answer (score 2):

**Without modification, the Canon EOS 550D** (Rebel T2i) **is *not* suitable for infrared photography**. Even with modification, the sensor stack of some Canon cameras still appears to be insensitive to IR compared with other cameras. There is likely an element, other than the hot mirror, that blocks a significant amount of IR. Based on a diagram in this [modification guide](http://dslrmodifications.com/rebelmod450d4.html), a potential culprit is the low-pass filter.

[image: sensor assembly]

Even **after modification, *high-quality* IR filters are needed.** Any visible light that makes it to the sensor will confuse the camera, and the resulting images will *not* have bright foliage characteristic of IR photos. The following were taken with a 550D that had the hot-mirror removed.

[image: RB channel swap]
[image: good filter]

See also:

- [Infrared Photography - How to set White Balance?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/26786/75526)
- [Infrared photography—why are green leaves not appearing as white?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/101480/75526)