# Infrared pics coming too red or with dark leaves (filters are top quality)

Tags: white-balance, infrared

[town square] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtABb.jpg)
[image: house, sidewall]
[image: swimming pool]
I have a canon xs for which I removed the anti-ir filter. Also, I am using a 24-105 with a heliopan 610nm for taking pics.

Under this assembly, I have this problem: foliage comes out too dark and it is impossible to fix it in post-processing. I tried shooting in raw, using a custom white balance with grass or a light grey pic as a reference, and still no success. Leaves come out dark same as in the picture above.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!!!!!!

Comment: What do your results look like without the 610nm filter?

Comment: How are you setting exposure? Manually? Auto? Using what parameters? Any EC?

Comment: @osullic This question was originally posted as an answer to [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/101480/infrared-photography-why-are-green-leaves-not-appearing-as-white), so I suspect it refers to the image in the question of that post. But yes, it should be clarified!

Comment: Hi, I am setting all in manual, using an f range from 9 to 14. Then I use the live view to select a proper shooting speed with my tripod. BTW, when I use the Haida 720nm it works like a charm. When I shoot without the 610nm filter the pic comes out kind of old fashion looking, sort like a lomo (I assume it is because of the IR light in the pic)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infrared photography—why are green leaves not appearing as white?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/101480/infrared-photography-why-are-green-leaves-not-appearing-as-white)

Comment: unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are expecting your results to look like what others get by removing the IR cut filter and then shooting without any type of filter. You won't get that effect with a 610nm filter in place.

Using a 610nm filter will darken much of the scene. A 610nm filter does not filter out 610nm wavelengths, it allows everything 610nm and longer to pass while attenuating the shorter wavelengths that make up most of the visible spectrum. If you want things that are yellow/green (like foliage and grass) to come out lighter when using the filter, you're going to need to expose brighter than what you're doing now.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I am enclosing some of the pics for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Did you convert the camera yourself?  If so, you should be aware that there are most likely [two pieces of glass](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/116473) you need to remove.  In addition to the IR-cut filter, which is easy to identify from its cyan tint, you need to remove the low-pass filter because it also blocks a significant amount of IR light.

Also, you are using a 610nm filter, which lets a significant amount of orange and red light through.  For the classic IR effect, try a 720nm or longer filter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I enclose a photo where I show what I removed: the blue filter from the plastic frame, replacing it with a piece of clear glass

Comment: For infrared photography, you need to remove two pieces of glass from a Canon DSLR.  For astrophotography, one may be enough.